# Order agnostic autoregressive sequence probability

Tags: machine-learning, probability, permutation

Autoregressive models define the following probability of a sequence $x$ as $p(x)=\Pi p(x_t | x_{<t})$ using the probability chain rule.

Then [Hoogeboom et al. 2022](https://openreview.net/forum?id=Lm8T39vLDTE) state that if we uniformly sample some permutation $\sigma$ (i.e if we consider the set of all permutations $S$, $\sigma \sim \operatorname{Unif}(S)$)  we have that $p(x)= E_\sigma p(x|\sigma)= E_\sigma [ \Pi p(x_{\sigma(t)} | x_{\sigma(<t)})]$

How is the latter equality $p(x)= E_\sigma p(x|\sigma)$ defined?

Comment: Hi, friendly tip: it's useful to link to the paper itself or provide a complete citation, as there are many papers that are "Hoogeboom et al. 2022", and the context of the paper helps to understand. I added a link, but please correct it if I incorrectly divined which paper you meant. I don't see the equality you claim within the paper. Which equation were you referring to

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I apologize for the vague question and I appreciate you adding a link.
I have edited the equation to make it explicit.

Comment: Thanks. I’ve voted to reopen the question.

Comment: Presumably $\sigma$ is random, right? The conditional expectation would be defined as always.  Otherwise, what is assumed about $\sigma$?

Comment: @whuber Yes $\sigma$ is a random permutation that is uniformly drawn from the set of all permutations.
I also edited the question for clarity

Comment: By considering the case of two times, where there are just two permutations, you ought to find the answer easy.  The general setting doesn't require any additional concepts or work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You said 'latter', but you explicitly wrote out the former, so I'll go with the equation you wrote. The explanation involves applying the definition of **expectation** and the **chain rule** of probability.

Each formula block below will add a new line to the ones before it.

We're told in [Hoogeboom et al. (2022)](https://openreview.net/forum?id=Lm8T39vLDTE) that
\begin{equation}
p(\boldsymbol{x}) = \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}_{\sigma \sim \mathcal{U}(S_D)} p(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \sigma)
\text{,}
\end{equation}
which is what you're interested in deriving.

1. Apply the definition of expectation.
   \begin{align}
   p(\boldsymbol{x}) &= \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}_{\sigma \sim \mathcal{U}(S_D)} p(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \sigma) \\
   &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_D} \left[ p_{\mathcal{U}}(\sigma) \cdot p(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \sigma) \right]
   \end{align}
2. Apply the chain rule of probability: $p(a, b) = p(a) p(b \mid a)$.
   \begin{align}
   p(\boldsymbol{x}) &= \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}_{\sigma \sim \mathcal{U}(S_D)} p(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \sigma) \\
   &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_D} \left[ p_{\mathcal{U}}(\sigma) \cdot p(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \sigma) \right] \\
   &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_D} p(\sigma, \boldsymbol{x})
   \end{align}
3. Use the law of total probability: $p(c) = \sum_{d} p(c, d)$.
   \begin{align}
   p(\boldsymbol{x}) &= \operatorname{\mathbb{E}}_{\sigma \sim \mathcal{U}(S_D)} p(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \sigma) \\
   &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_D} \left[ p_{\mathcal{U}}(\sigma) \cdot p(\boldsymbol{x} \mid \sigma) \right] \\
   &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_D} p(\sigma, \boldsymbol{x}) \\
   &= p(\boldsymbol{x}) \qquad \blacksquare
   \end{align}

Comment: Wow, I totally missed marginalizing out the $\sigma$.
This was indeed a very straightforward equality- thanks for the help